# update a list when deleting a site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-deletion

I have a SPList on root site which contains all Sites which have been created under this site collection. Now I want to update the SPList when you remvoe (delete) one of the sites. I don't know how. Is there a way, feature activation when you remove a site?

Comment: You have the [Web Deleted event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebeventreceiver.webdeleted.aspx)

Comment: Steve B, I guess that's the correct answer and you can post is as answer :)